# How to concatenate query result in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, concatenation

I want to concatenate the query result in c#. Below is the resulting image

[image]

In my code, I have done

```
using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(conn.ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT m.`read_param` FROM mdc_request m WHERE m.`row_id` = @row_id";
            cn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@row_id", iterations.row_id);

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // here I want to save the result in one single variable
            }
        }
```

**Update 1**

As per @Rahul answer, I have done the following

```
public async Task YtlbusMethod(List<Iterations> ytlbus)
    {
        MySqlConnection cn = null;
        int limitRequest = 10;
        for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--)
        {
            foreach (var item in ytlbus)
            {

                using (cn = new MySqlConnection(conn.ConnectionString))
                {
                    string query = "SELECT m.`time` FROM `mdc_meter_config` m WHERE m.`row_id` = @row_id";
                    cn.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@row_id", item.row_id);

                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string time = (string)reader["time"];
                        if(item.time == time)
                        {
                            int sleeptime = Convert.ToInt32(item.time);
                            sleeptime = sleeptime * 1000;

                            Thread.Sleep(sleeptime);
                            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PortHitmethod(item));
                        }
                    }

                }

                cn.Close();


                // select query kerni hy ..jis main wohi data ay jo tu yahan pass ker raha hy... where k ander just tuny row id pass kerni hy. 

                //if(item.time== query main jo time aya hy woh)
                //{

                //}
            }
        }

    }
public async Task PortHitmethod(Iterations iterations)
    {
        MySqlConnection cn = null;
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        using (cn = new MySqlConnection(conn.ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT m.`read_param` FROM mdc_request m WHERE m.`row_id` = @row_id";
            cn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@row_id", iterations.row_id);

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                data.Add(reader["read_param"].ToString());
            }


        }
        cn.Close();
        var single = string.Join("", data);
    }
```

Now the issue that I am facing is that I am unable to get all the rows data. The total rows are `9` but I am getting less than that

How can I achieve this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Then create a single variable `List<string>` (the results seems to be strings) and add at each loop the current element from the reader to the list

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenate"? What (C#) type do you expect the result to have?

Comment: @NetMage by concatenating I mean that I want to save all the incoming data into one single variable. The data type will be a string

Comment: @Steve I have tried Rahul's way but still have some issues. You can see my `update 1`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like those are integer value then you can do something like

```
        List<int> data = new List<int>;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            data.Add(int.Parse(reader["read_param"].ToString()));
        }
```

Then you can use `string.Join()` method like

```
var single = string.Join(",", data);
```

Comment: `var single = string.Join(",", data);` outside the `using statement`?

Comment: I have tried your way. Still facing an issue please see my `update 1`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Rahul, your code should be:
Your update 1 is different code.
What do you want to achieve here.

```
    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(conn.ConnectionString))
    {
        string query = "SELECT m.`read_param` FROM mdc_request m WHERE m.`row_id` = @row_id";
        cn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@row_id", iterations.row_id);

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            data.Add(reader["read_param"].ToString());
        }
    }

    var single = string.Join("", data);
```

Comment: the data is in string